# restoring drop-down in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

Any idea why the drop-down does not set its initial value?  The initial load says "Choose..." but instead I would like it to say "NCI Values" as provided in the initial JSON at the very bottom.

Ideally, I would like the save JSON to not contain every item in the drop down.  This is the reason why I have that data structure coming from a different source.  I'm having trouble getting the drop down to re-select the right item using the string.

http://jsfiddle.net/jslim180/gcnaY/

```
<div data-bind="with: compound">

    <h3>Dose Form</h3>
    <select
        data-bind="options: $root.compoundDoseForm,
                       optionsText: 'name',
                       value: doseForm,
                       optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>

</div>
<p>
    <button data-bind='click: $root.save'>Save to JSON</button>
</p>
<textarea data-bind='value: $root.lastSavedJson' rows='5' cols='60'> </textarea>
<script>
    var Compound = function(data) {
        data = data || {};
        this.doseForm = ko.observable(data.doseForm);
    }

    var CompoundsModel = function(compound) {
        var self = this;
        self.compound = ko.observable(compound);
        self.compoundDoseForm = ko.observableArray([ {
            code : "AA",
            name : "NCI Values"
        }, {
            code : "",
            name : "Not Specified"
        } ]);

        this.save = function() {
            self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.compound), null, 2));
        };
        self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("");
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new CompoundsModel(new Compound({
        "doseForm" : {
            "code" : "AA",
            "name" : "NCI Values"
        }
    })));
</script>
```

Comment: simple . just remove options caption :) cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to abandon the "name" and "code" format and use only an array of strings for the drop-down.  This is reasonable because I guarantee that the items are unique and I can convert them back to codes for storage.

```
<div data-bind="with: compound">

    <h3>Dose Form</h3>
    <select
        data-bind="options: $root.compoundDoseForm, value: doseForm,
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose dose form...'"></select>

</div>
<p>
    <button data-bind='click: $root.save'>Save to JSON</button>
</p>
<textarea data-bind='value: $root.lastSavedJson' rows='5' cols='60'> </textarea>
<script>
    var Compound = function(data) {
        data = data || {};
        this.doseForm = ko.observable(data.doseForm);
    }

    var CompoundsModel = function(compound) {
        var self = this;
        self.compound = ko.observable(compound);
        self.compoundDoseForm = ko.observableArray([ "NCI Values", "Not Specified" ]);

        this.save = function() {
            self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.compound), null, 2));
        };
        self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("");
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new CompoundsModel(new Compound({
        "doseForm" : "NCI Values"
    })));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something here? If so, please explain and I will update my answer.

Otherwise, if you don't want "choose.." to be the initial value (which is only display text, not a value) then remove your `optionsCaption`, which would then select the first item in the list instead:

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.compoundDoseForm,
                   optionsText: 'name',
                   value: doseForm"></select>
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcnaY/1/)**

You would use the `optionsCaption` if you don't have a default option or you want to force the user to select something and have validation to back it up if it's a required field.

Comment: Earlier this value does start out empty and I do need to force the user to choose.  I'm very glad you explained this, it is not obvious to me.  Thank you...

Comment: It appeared to work, but the drop-down was simply showing the 1st value.  I have updated the default to try and set it to the second value in the drop-down to no avail `http://jsfiddle.net/jslim180/gcnaY/3/`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the select data-bind to this:

```
    <select data-bind="options: $root.compoundDoseForm,
                   optionsText: 'name',
                   optionsValue: 'code',
                   value: $root.compound().doseForm().code,
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

Comment: Works, thank you.  Because this is withing the scope of `with: compound,` this `$root.compound().doseForm().code` can be shortened to just `doseForm().code`

Comment: Drop-down populates, but after changing the value the save JSON did not reflect the new value.